# O que é $scope.answer?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

Sou novo com AngularJS, gostaria de entender para que realmente serve o $scope.answer, não encontrei nada na documentação oficial e nem na web, apenas vi ele em um exemplo que peguei em um tutorial, mas não entendi a importância dele

Comment: Victor bem-vindo ao [pt.so], clique em [edit] abaixo da sua pergunta e coloque o código que você está com dúvida. Provavelmente `answer` é uma propriedade que foi criada dentro de `$scope`. Veja [Como criar um exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) e visite a [help] para entender como funciona o site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$scope` é um objeto que referencia o modelo de aplicação que provê um contexto de execução para aplicações - diferentes contextos possuem um `$scope` diferente.

Um `$scope` pode ser compartilhado entre estruturas hierárquicas (controles pai-filho), assim como propagar eventos.

`$scope.answer` é, provavelmente, apenas uma variável criada no escopo de execução. Não pertence à implementação padrão do Angular.